# Automated sync to/from document management system and a physical Windows directory? (Autonomy iManage Worksite 8.5)

Tags: windows, sync, document-management

Is there a way to set up a user-created job that periodically exports newly created or modified files from a designated Autonomy iManage Worksite 8.5 workspace document folder to a designated Windows directory/path, and/or vice-versa?

As a little background, I am a patent attorney who uses the USPTO online PAIR and Electronic Filing Systems a lot.  I came from a small boutique firm that used Windows directories for file management, and I recently joined a large GP that uses iManage.  It is irritating to have to keep track of two sets of files, one on a document management server, and another on my machine or a Windows server from where I can upload/download documents via the internet.  If it is possible to sync files between an iManage folder and a Windows directory,  it would be helpful, as then I could just work from the Windows folder when dealing with downloading or uploading documents.  Preferably the sync should be two-way, as for most other things I would prefer to work within iManage.  This is because adding a document to an iManage with the same Windows file name as another document in the same document folder does not delete the latter file; rather, it creates a new file (whose physical file name on the iManage server is just a number) with the same "description" (an iManage docuemnt property that a Windows file name maps to.).  What's more, "deleting" the older versions of the files on iManage is cumbersome - you have to right click, select "move," select the destination folder "to be deleted," and then select whether you want to update file metadata, security settings, etc. to the new location.

If I am mistaken and there is actually a way to download/upload directly to/from an iManage document folder (perhaps with a browser extension/plug-in that interfaces upload "browse" buttons on websites with iManage instead of, or in addition to, Windows directories?), I would like to know that as well.

There is a "portable" Windows directory on which iManage files are stored locally on my machine when I have them open or "checked out," but it is cumbersome to upload files from that directory because (1) you have to "check out" the files first, and (2) you have to cross-reference the file description to the arbitrary number that is the actual physical file name so that you know what file you are selecting to upload.

Thanks for any suggestions!